# Problems with 10G networking under Linux

Tags: linux, networking

We are currently encountering problems with different 10G network cards under linux.

I know that it's difficult to "solve" problems / answer questions like this but we are a bit helpless. So please be kind :-)

First we tried Intel 10G adapter (X*710). They worked fine until we saw "tx hang" in the kernel message log.

We tried everything. Newest firmware, newest kernel (4.19, 4.14. 4.20, 5.x), we used the kernel i40e driver and the one from intel. We searched the net, tried all the steps like disabling TSO or LRO. Nothing helped. The "tx hang" occurred multiple times a day. All connections are lost until the kernel watchdog restarts the connection. It takes about 1-2 minutes.

So we tried Mellanox cards. They do almost the same. After some hours all network adapter went down and up again. Just the kernel log messages are not there, maybe because the driver does not log that.

We tried all cards (4 of each manufacturer) on 3 different machines to exclude other hardware errors or bugs. We tried different SPF+ modules (also 8) and cabling (9) and other switches (2 large HP procurve).

Does anyone have any idea what to look for else?

Maybe some kernel config options (we use vanilla kernel which worked perfectly under 1G equipment)?

Some other hardware issue?

Comment: Post your full adapter configuration, including any `ethtool` or similar settings.  Note that if you are disabling autonegotiation, you are breaking the 10G standard.  Autonegotiation is a **required** part of gigabit and faster networking.  See http://noahdavids.org/self_published/gigabit-AN.html for cites to the IEEE 802.3 standard (not freely available)  See also http://www.ieee802.org/3/an/public/jul04/lynskey_2_0704.pdf documenting the requirement of the standard.

Comment: I think it's a driver/kernel bug similar problems were reported [https://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/bugs/583/](https://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/bugs/583/)

Answer (score 3):

Recently I was working as a network/system engineer in a company that was massively using 10G network infrastructure, and like most of the experienced network engineers that started their career in the early 00s, I was sticking to Intel-manufactured network adapters, but in the processs of deploying 10G network infrastructure I encountered lots of issues, and I can summarize them below. I should also say that this is my personal experience, someone's else experience may vary radically.

- there are several Intel 10G/40G chipsets and some of them are troublesome and some are not. For instance EoL X520 chipset is decent and we saw no problems with it in the production environment. We were using X520-DA2 adapters.
- when it comes to X*710, there are several factors to consider:
- there's X710 and XL710 chipset. X710 is used in 10G adapters, and XL710 is used in 40G adapters.
- there are several sub-manufacturers of network adapters that ship tampered X710 adapters under their name, for example Supermicro. Avoid using these, they are badly designed and poorly supported. Intel NVM firmwares are incompatible with these, and Supermicro NVM images are hard to obtain, delayed in time, and Intel technical support refuses to support such adapters, stating that "these are not manufactured by us".
- in the same time ***original, Intel-manufactured*** X710 adapters are decent, stable and cool, my former employer still has dozens of servers running original Intel-manufactured network adapters. However, we had to replace all of the Supermicro-tampered X710 ones.
- **disclaimer: personal opinion**. XL710 chipset, regardless of the submanufacturer, is a dead one. I saw several unanswered bugreports, all stating the problem you are facing: complains from kernel about timeouts, adapters stopping working as soon as some considerable traffic appears on the wire and so on. Regardless of the OS used: Linux, FreeBSD, etc. Intel techsupport failed to solve these (typical [thread](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P0000490Vf6SAE/xl710-malicious-driver-detection-event-occured?language=en_US)). I have seen a non-official feedback from network engineers working for large enterprises and the feedback was the same: don't ever use the XL710 chipset in production (you can google those using "malicious driver detection event" as one of the patterns); they were trying to, but it was futile: they were proposing to use theis "proper" DAC-cables instead of the "generic ones", "proper" SFP+ trancievers instead of general ones (and since there are only 3-5 original SPF+ tranciever manufacturers, I doubt there would be any real difference). I can say that we switched to Mellanox 40G cards (Connect-X based ones) and its was okay since that (and that was the advice that my colleagues gave me; same thing about older Connect-X 10G chipsets). We didn't replace a single thing in the rest of the infrastructure: DAC cables/SFP+ trancievers stayed the same. This isn't a Mellanox ad, there are several vendors shipping 40G adapters - Chelsio, Solarflare, you can stick to any of them, all are reported to be working. Reason why we switched to Mellanox was trivial: lots of used adapters on the aftermarket.

As a potential solution I can say that you should try running latest NVM image on your cards, but I am very pessimistic about these. From my experience - these updates solve nothing. I also still have several adapters that after update stopped being recognized as Intel adapter that can be burned with a new version (however, they continued to "fuction").

**Follow-up:** as far as I can see, there is still some hope: according to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1779756) (sic ! notice the date !), some Linux distributions now have the patches needed. But, considering the amount of time passed since the original discovery of the problem (several years, jeez !) and the fact that Intel took almost no action to investigate/solve this issue from their side for ***major networked OS***, I would conclude that XL710 is one of the biggest failures in the history of network ICs production. Keep up the good work, Intel.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH for your effort. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Can you confirm or not that Mellanox MT27500 works with you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot confirm these are okay since we have more recent MT27700 and MT26448 cards from ConnectX-4 and ConnectX-2. But I think yours are worth trying, it's previous ConnectX-3 generation, and I really think they will be okay (cannot guarantee though).

Comment: We successfully testet MT27500 with kernel 4.14 and it works like a charm.